# Error creating bean with name defined in class path resource [application-context.xml] in spring framework

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

```
<bean id="MyDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="${url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg value="MyDataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

> Error creating bean with name 'template' defined in class path
>   resource [application-context.xml]: Could not resolve matching
>   constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple
>   parameters to avoid type ambiguities)

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here to get above error? Have all of it defined in properties file correctly with correct variable name. what are the things to check for ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

change

```
<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg value="MyDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

to

```
<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="MyDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

because you don't want to inject `String` value you want to inject referred bean

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and in my bean class, I declared the default constructor which was not declared earlier and it solved my problem.

So My complete error is like
**Error creating bean with name 'student1' defined in class path resource [config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.springcore.springcore.Student]: *No default constructor found*; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.springcore.springcore.Student.()**